# Unit testing angular.js service (node.js server) in controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-mocha

I'm new to the unit testing in the client side. My application uses the express.js, angularjs-ui-router and node.js. Currently i start writing the unit test cases for the application. I'm using Karma, Mocha, Chai, Sinon for unit testing.

My router config look like below:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('drive', {
            url: '/drive',
            templateUrl: 'drive.jade',
            controller: 'driveCtrl',
        });
```

Controller:

```
 angular.module('mApp').controller('driveCtrl', ['$scope', 'driveService',
 function($scope, driveService) {
    var driveInfo = driveService.get({}, function() {});
    driveInfo.$promise.then(function(rs) {
            var drivers = [];
            //Logical operation
            $scope.drivers = drivers;
    });
}]);
```

Factory Resource:

```
mApp.factory('driveService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/drive/id/:id/', {id:'@id'});
  }]);
```

The driveService is a factory which insides uses a angular.js $resources. I tried variety of options but nothings seems to be working (using the $httpbackend, $q). Can you help me out to write the way to test the controller by mocking the driveService.

Here's my unit test code:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var sinon = require('sinon');

describe('Drive Service initialisation', function() {
    var scope, controller, state, $q, mockDriveService, driveServiceResponse = [{name:'james', type: 'heavy'}], queryDeferred;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('mApp'));

    angular.mock.module(function($provide){
            $provide.value('driveService', mockDriveService);
        });

    describe(' drive service called', function() {

      beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $state, _$q_, driveService) {
        $q = _$q_;  
        scope = $rootScope.$new(); 

        mockDriveService = {
            get:function(){
                queryDeferred = $q.defer();
                queryDeferred.resolve(driveServiceResponse);
                return {$promise: queryDeferred.promise};
            }
        };
        controller = $controller('driveCtrl', { $scope: scope, driveService:driveService}); 
        sinon.stub(mockDriveService, 'get');
        scope.$apply();
      }));

      it('expect filter to be empty', function () {
        expect(scope.drivers).to.not.be.empty;
      });

    });
  });
```

The error what i'm getting is:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /driveService/id
No more request expected
    at $httpBackend (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1210:9)
    at sendReq (public/javascripts/lib/angular/angular.js:10333:9)
    at serverRequest (public/javascripts/lib/angular/angular.js:10045:16)
    at processQueue (public/javascripts/lib/angular/angular.js:14567:28)
    at public/javascripts/lib/angular/angular.js:14583:27
    at Scope.$eval (public/javascripts/lib/angular/angular.js:15846:28)
    at Scope.$digest (public/javascripts/lib/angular/angular.js:15657:31)
    at Scope.$apply (public/javascripts/lib/angular/angular.js:15951:24)
    at Context.<anonymous> (C:/Users/por/AppData/Local/Temp/b0475694b46e0d60262621ad126ce46c.browserify:63:9)
    at Object.invoke (public/javascripts/lib/angular/angular.js:4450:17)
Error: Declaration Location
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2375:25)
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Please, specify your current specs. Asking to write them from scratch isn't really a question.

Comment: i'm not expected one to write. anyway i can post what i written.

Comment: Please, post them then, they are relevant to the question.

Comment: @estus: here you go. I tried to resolve this error but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a mocked service but still providing unmocked `driveService` for controller (this has been already done by default).

The fact that `driveService.get` is stubbed after the controller was instantiated and the method was called, doesn't help the case.

It should be something like

```
    mockDriveService = {
        get: sinon.stub().returns({$promise: $q.resolve(driveServiceResponse)})
    };
    controller = $controller('driveCtrl', { $scope: scope, driveService:mockDriveService}); 
    scope.$apply();
```

The app should have test-friendly design to be tested efficiently. Considering that router is loaded in top-level module and its configuration is defined there too, app units that are supposed to be tested should be defined in child modules, so they could be tested in isolation.

The app may be refactored as

```
angular.module('mApp', ['ui.router', 'mApp.drive']);
...
angular.module('mApp.drive', [])
.controller('driveCtrl', ...)
.factory('driveService', ...);
```

And its units may be tested like

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('mApp.drive'));
...
```

Comment: After the changes are applied in my code, getting the same error but request to other JADE template (that's what the error shows). It means the request is going to a different template. Do i needs to check anything else ? here's the error     `Error: Unexpected request: GET partials/customer.jade
        No more request expected
            at $httpBackend (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1210:9)
            at sendReq (public/javascripts/lib/angular/angular.js:10333:9)
            at serverRequest (public/javascripts/lib/angular/angular.js:10045:16)
            at process`

Comment: Real requests can't and shouldn't be performed in unit tests, this is why you get this error. It is router that triggers http request. Router module and router configuration shouldn't be loaded in unit tests at all.

Comment: you mean loading the angular-ui-router in the karma is wrong ? or even loading the http triggering files also ?

Comment: You may load it in Karma, it doesn't hurt. You just don't need to load its module in spec.  I.e. `mApp` shouldn't be loaded, instead its children modules  that don't depend on `ui.router` module should. Every http request should be mocked. If this request isn't done by the unit that is tested in current spec, this is bad.

Comment: i'm really clueless about how it works. But when i change the scope.$apply to scope.$digest. Everything is start working. Thanks alot for your help.. kindly make the change in your answer so that i can accept it.(If you know, how it works kindly explain, so that it will help someone)

Comment: `scope.$digest`, isn't a solution to the problem and won't help to test the app. It is just a hack that incidentally works. $digest doesn't trigger a digest on root scope, and $apply does. The router activates the state on root digest and screws the things up. The way to avoid this is to not have router and its configuration loaded.

Comment: Yup. you are correct. Let me unload all the router config and files and check.. Thanks for the input

Comment: I've updated the answer to give a hint on how it is supposed to look like. The thing that I didn't mention is that `angular.mock.module(function($provide){ ... }` in your code is incorrect for two reasons. It isn't in `beforeEach` and won't function properly. And it precedes the definition of `mockDriveService`, which is really bad (it is `undefined` on first spec and is equal to `mockDriveService` from previous spec if there are multiple specs, nasty things will happen). For controller testing it is just not necessary and can be removed.